# Watch multiple events in angular and trigger when all events have fired

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling, dom-events

Is it possible to wait for an array of events to trigger and then execute a function? I know, it is possible to watch all the events individually and keep track on which events have fired, but isn't there any built in functionality for this?

Something like this:

```
$scope.$on(["event1", "event2", "event3"], function () {
    // All events fired do stuff
});
```

Events are broadcast like this:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('event1');
```

Comment: are you looking for the implementation or something built in?

Comment: Preferably built in. I guess implementation is fine too if built in functionality isn't available.

Comment: I think there is no such a thing: and it needs some clarification: what do you actually mean by "all events fired"? For what period of time? Can something "cancel" one of those firings?

Comment: Anyway, I'd better create some array inside the `$rootScope` and then watch for it's changing. Once all it's keys are `true` - call a handler

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, would have made this a comment, but don't have enough reputation to do that yet :)

I don't think there actually is anything like that, but a (probably somewhat obvious) question is if you are handling all events in the same way, why not give them all the same name?

Alternatively if its out of your control (say, for example, they come from an external library), you could just define a separate named function and then point each of the listeners to that named function:

```
["event1", "event2", "event3"].forEach(function (eventName) {
    $scope.$on(eventName, listenerFunction);
});

function listenerFunction (event, data) {
    // do something with event and data
}
```

Comment: That's not an answer. You have to call `listenerFunction` only when all events have been fired